# Field with optional zod type but required on swagger

Tags: nestjs, swagger, zod, nestjs-swagger

I have this

```
const FinesListPaginatedQuerySchema = z.object({ dateFrom: z.coerce.date().optional()})
export class FinesListPaginatedRequestQueryDto extends createZodDto(FinesListPaginatedQuerySchema) {}
```

and my controller is

```
 public findFines(@Query() query: FinesListPaginatedRequestQueryDto))
```

I want that my field will be optional but on swagger I see only required

UPD

There is interesting moment. When I have got two fields on my `FinesListPaginatedQuerySchema` (optional and required) its ok. But when its optional and optional, my fields become required. It happens on  `const reflectedParam = Reflect.getMetadata(constants_1.DECORATORS.API_MODEL_PROPERTIES, prototype, key)` returns params without required option(I don't know why if I have only optional parameters it equal undefined)

Comment: where is `createZodDto` coming from? Is it built-in to Zod or Swagger, is it from a different package, or did you make it yourself?

Comment: @Samathingamajig it from '@anatine/zod-nestjs'